# HTML 5 Canvas Animation - Move multiple objects one after another

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have this animation which moves a row of circles from A(x,y) to B(x,y). ButI'm having trouble trying to replicate this into an array of circles where each row moves (one after another) from A to B. However, I also want to maintain the original location of the array so that essentially, it makes a copy of the row and moves the copy. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have edited the code so that it now has two rows that remain stationary when one is moving - but now, I want to be able to move more than one row (as described in the example below).

EDIT 2: Here's a jsfiddle instead so it's easier to understand what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLvk1bsc/2/

For example, I want to emulate something like this.

ORIGINAL ----------------- NEW

1. r r r r r r. --------------- A. g g g g g g
2. p p p p p p  ------------   B. r r r r r r
3. g g g g g g  ------------   C. r r r r r r

The sequence of the animation would therefore be as follows:

1. 3 --- a. A copy of row 3 moves to row A
2. 1 --- b. A copy of row 1 moves to row B
3. 1 --- c. A copy of row 1 moves to row C

   ```
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

   window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
       return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
           window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
       };
   })();

   setTimeout(function () {
       draw();
       animate(movingRow2);
   }, 100);

   var movingRow = [];
   var frozenRow = [];

   var cx = 50;
   var cy = 70;

   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       movingRow.push({ x: cx, y: cy, borderWidth: 1, color: "orange"});
       frozenRow.push({ x: cx, y: cy, borderWidth: 1, color: "blue"});

       cx += 40;
   }

   var movingRow2 = [];
   var frozenRow2 = [];

   var cx = 50;
   var cy = 110;

   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       movingRow2.push({ x: cx, y: cy, borderWidth: 1, color: "green"});
       frozenRow2.push({ x: cx, y: cy, borderWidth: 1, color: "pink"});

       cx += 40;
   }

   function drawCircle(myCircle, context) {
       context.beginPath();
       context.arc(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
       context.fillStyle = myCircle.color;
       context.fill();
       context.stroke();
       context.closePath();
   }   

   function draw() {
       context.save();
       context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       for (var i = 0; i < movingRow.length; i++) {
           drawCircle(movingRow[i], context);
           drawCircle(frozenRow[i], context);

           drawCircle(movingRow2[i], context);
           drawCircle(frozenRow2[i], context);
      }
   }

   var newX = 320;
   var newY = 70;

   var pathArray = [];

   pathArray.push({
       x: movingRow2[0].x,
       y: movingRow2[0].y
   });

   pathArray.push({
       x: newX,
       y: newY
   });

   var polyPoints = makePolyPoints(pathArray);

   var position = 0;
   var speed = 1;

   function animate(m) {

       // calculate the new position
       position += speed;

       if (position > polyPoints.length - 1) {
           return;
       }

       // a single point in the array
       var pt = polyPoints[position];

       var step = 0;

       // update x and y
       for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
           m[i].x = pt.x + step;
           m[i].y = pt.y;

           step += 40;
       }

       draw();

       // request new frame
       requestAnimationFrame(function() {
           animate(m);
       });
   }

   function makePolyPoints(pathArray) {

       // list of points for each frame of the shape
       var points = [];
       // how quickly the transition occurs
       var speed = 150;

       for (var i = 1; i < pathArray.length; i++) {

           var startPt = pathArray[i - 1];
           var endPt = pathArray[i];

           // calculate difference between start and end points 
           var dx = endPt.x - startPt.x;
           var dy = endPt.y - startPt.y;

           for (var n = 0; n <= speed; n++) {  
               // calculate the x and y positions for each frame
               var x = startPt.x + dx * n / speed;
               var y = startPt.y + dy * n / speed;

               // append the points to the array to be used in the animation
               points.push({
                   x: x,
                   y: y
               });
           }
       }

       return points;
   }
   ```

Comment: can you set up a pen? http://codepen.io/

Comment: Hey Alan, I've added a jsfiddle on the main question if that's what you mean? Wasn't familiar with codepen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();



setTimeout(function () {
    draw();
    var a = anims[anims_i];
    animate(a[0], a[1]);
}, 100);

var rowA = [];
var rowB = [];
var rowC = [];

var cx = 50;
var cy = 70;

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    rowA.push({ x: cx, y: cy-40, borderWidth: 1, color: "orange"});
    rowB.push({ x: cx, y: cy, borderWidth: 1, color: "blue"});
    rowC.push({ x: cx, y: cy+40, borderWidth: 1, color: "pink"});
    cx += 40;
}

var rowACopy1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowA));
var rowACopy2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowA));
var rowCCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowC));

var offsetX = 270;
var polyPointsA1 = makePolyPoints([
  {x: rowA[0].x, y: rowA[0].y},
  {x: rowB[0].x+offsetX, y: rowB[0].y}
]);

var polyPointsA2 = makePolyPoints([
  {x: rowA[0].x, y: rowA[0].y},
  {x: rowC[0].x+offsetX, y: rowC[0].y}
]);

var polyPointsC = makePolyPoints([
  {x: rowC[0].x, y: rowC[0].y},
  {x: rowA[0].x+offsetX, y: rowA[0].y}
]);

var anims = [
 [rowCCopy, polyPointsC],
 [rowACopy1, polyPointsA1],
 [rowACopy2, polyPointsA2]
];

var anims_i = 0;

function drawCircle(myCircle, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = myCircle.color;
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
}   

function draw() {
    context.save();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < rowA.length; i++) {
        drawCircle(rowA[i], context);
        drawCircle(rowB[i], context);
        drawCircle(rowC[i], context);

        drawCircle(rowACopy1[i], context);
        drawCircle(rowACopy2[i], context);
        drawCircle(rowCCopy[i], context);
   }
}

var position = 0;
var speed = 1;

function animate(m, polyPoints) {

    // calculate the new position
    position += speed;

    if (position > polyPoints.length - 1) {
      position = 0;
      anims_i++;
        if (anims_i < anims.length) {
          var a = anims[anims_i];
          requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            animate(a[0], a[1]);
          });
        }
        return;
    }

    // a single point in the array
    var pt = polyPoints[position];

    var step = 0;

    // update x and y
    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        m[i].x = pt.x + step;
        m[i].y = pt.y;

        step += 40;
    }

    draw();

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        animate(m, polyPoints);
    });
}

function makePolyPoints(pathArray) {

    // list of points for each frame of the shape
    var points = [];
    // how quickly the transition occurs
    var speed = 150;

    for (var i = 1; i < pathArray.length; i++) {

        var startPt = pathArray[i - 1];
        var endPt = pathArray[i];

        // calculate difference between start and end points 
        var dx = endPt.x - startPt.x;
        var dy = endPt.y - startPt.y;

        for (var n = 0; n <= speed; n++) {  
            // calculate the x and y positions for each frame
            var x = startPt.x + dx * n / speed;
            var y = startPt.y + dy * n / speed;

            // append the points to the array to be used in the animation
            points.push({
                x: x,
                y: y
            });
        }
    }

    return points;
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="580"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey wolfhammer, thank you for this, really appreciate this! It's very close to what I'm looking for. Instead of moving up and down, I intended to move the copy across so that you have the original and new circles side by side i.e. the x co-ordinates of the moving ones would be like 200. Also, how can I get it so that it does the movements one by one rather than all in one go i.e. it moves row1, stops, moves row2, stops, moves row3, stops? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I added the right shift so and animation ordering.  You should be able to position it from there if it's not exact.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yup, I can sort that out, really appreciate it :)